# react-native: Position child element relative to device and not parent

Tags: react-native

I have a child element `<Child />` inside `<Parent height="40"/>` I want to absolutely position the child element relative to the device view area and not a parent.

example layout

```js
<device height="1000">
  <header height="500">
    <ScrollView />
    <parent height=40">
    <child height="300" top="150" />
  </parent>
</device>
```

`position="absolute"` is relative to parent and there is no `position="fixed"`

Comment: did you any solution for this problem ? İf u find could u share it ?

Answer (score 8):

**Relative :** Relative to it’s current position, but can be moved. Or A RELATIVE positioned element is positioned relative to ITSELF.

**Absolute :** In React Native, an ABSOLUTE positioned element is positioned relative to IT'S CLOSEST PARENT. If that parent happens to be a box that covers the entire viewport of your device, then it works like fixed (the child can be positioned relative to the device). [Better explanation here from the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#position).

What the official docs recommends (seen in above link): If you want to position a child relative to something that is not its parent [in your case it would be the device viewport], don't use styles for that. Use the component tree. For that see solution #2.

### Solution 1:

here is a demo: https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/7ee9c4

you can use the [Portal](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/portal.html) from [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/portal.html) to position child compoent from device not from parent

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Portal, Text, Provider as PaperProvider } from "react-native-paper";

const Child=()=>{
return (
  <Text>This is Child component which take positioned from Parent</Text>
    )
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Portal>
            <Child />
          </Portal>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  Î;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
  },
});

const JSX = () => {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <App />
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

export default JSX;
```

### Solution 2:

**place Child outside of parent and give position:"absolute"**

like this

```
<device height="1000">

 <header height="500">
 <ScrollView />
 <parent height=40">
 </parent>

 <child height="300" style={{position:"absolute",top:150}} />

</device>
```

Comment: I know that works. But what if you have deep nested components at some points it's hard to put the component back at the root tree ?

Comment: then you can use the portal from react-native-paper or from other packages to render at a different place https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/portal.html and i update my answer

Comment: @LoganWlv I have updated my answer now you can check

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to achieve the same result without any library ?

Comment: @LoganWlv yes it is possible you can make your on portal login with context api https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/5a658a2d765cf8bf5e09594059faaa073dfb51da/src/components/Portal/Portal.tsx

Comment: @LoganWlv did you test with portal?

Comment: I do not want to use an other external library. A solution I found is sending a Redux action to enable the absolute <div> at the top of the tree (kinda like your second solution).

Comment: @LoganWlv yeah, you are right we can also achieve it from redux or HOC. i want to know about the bounty

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-portal you can also use this tiny library.

Comment: @LoganWlv thanks for bounty i would be thankful if you accept my answer and upvote